# Angular UI-Bootstrap typeahead in table

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

Simple question really, but how can I setup the typeahead to work in a table that works off of a different table than my typeahead?

For Example, I have a foreign key in a table and I want to let the users select this key based on the respective NAME value in the foreign key's primary table.

Code Example:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped rwd-table" id="page-wrap">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Primary ID</th>
        <th>Foreign Key (As Name)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in PrimaryTable" id="display">
        <td data-th="ID">{{p.PrimaryID}}</td>
        <td>
            <input id="ForeignKeyName"
                   type="text"
                   ng-model="p.ForeignKeyID"
                   uib-typeahead="f.ForeignKeyID as f.ForeignKeyName for f in ForeignKeyTable | filter:$viewValue"                               
                   class="form-control">
        </td>                   
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

With this example, I would want the users to see the "Foreign Key (As Name)" As the Name value instead of the ID value. The trick is that I also want the underlying value to be the ID and have it mapped to match the original value, as notified by the ng-model.

UPDATE: Another question I had that was in line with the previous one is how do I setup my ng-model to show the `ForeignKeyTable.ForeignKeyName` in place of the `PrimaryTable.ForeignKeyID`?

This would be similar ( I imagine) to how the uib-typeahead matches the `ForeignKeyTable.ForeignKeyID` and `ForeignKeyTable.ForeignKeyName` but with the two seperate tables?

What I would desire is to be able to put `ng-model: PrimaryTable.ForeignKeyID as ForeignKeyTable.ForeignKeyName`

Comment: I dont' really understand the concept here. Can you share some sample data stored in `PrimaryTable` and the `ForeignKeyTable`? Are they related in some way?

Comment: Basically Primary Table contains a column that links to the ForeignKeyTable's Identifying ID Column. In other words, a row from PrimaryTable could be {ID:1, ForeignKeyID: 18, ...} and the corresponding ForeignKeyTable Row could be {ForeignKeyID: 18, ForeignKeyName: 'Apple', ...}.   With this data, I am basically wanting the users to be able to type/select 'Apple' and the corresponding value that the table uses should be 18.

Comment: but should this 18 be value from `PrimaryTableRow.ForeignKeyID` or `ForeignKeyTableRow.ForeignKeyID` ?

Comment: The initial value for the column would be based on the `PrimaryTableRow.ForeignKeyID` for that row. So if the row has 18 in its ForeignKeyID Column, it would use that as the starting point. Then I want the user to be able to select from the list based on ForeignKeyTable, and at that point any selection there would replace the 18 value from the PrimaryTable with whatever corresponding `ForeignKeyTableRow.ForeignKeyID` from the `ForeignKeyTableRow.ForeignKeyName` that is selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing would be updating `PrimaryKeyTable` rows every time user selects value in typeahead. You'll have to catch selected item and manually assign its `ForeignKeyId` value to the row of `PrimaryTable`.
The way to do it is to add `typeahead-on-select` directive to your typeahead and bind it to the function that assigns the values for you.

It would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in PrimaryTable" id="display">
    <td data-th="ID">{{p.PrimaryID}}</td>
    <td>
        <input id="ForeignKeyName"
                   type="text"
                   ng-model="selectedItem" <!-- could be anything really for we will not use it here -->
                   uib-typeahead="f.ForeignKeyID as f.ForeignKeyName for f in ForeignKeyTable | filter:$viewValue"   
                   typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label, p)"                            
                   class="form-control">
    </td>                   
</tr>
```

**Inside your controller**

```
$scope.onSelect = function($item, $model, $label, primaryKeyTableRow) {
    primaryKeyTableRow.ForeignKeyId = $item.ForeignKeyId;
}
```

Next step is to display `name` property value of `ForeignKeyTable` row that corresponds to `ForeignKeyId` from `PrimaryKeyTable` in each row. Since we have to filter `ForeignKeyTable` to find suitable item it would be a good idea to put that logic inside the controller. For there are multiple rows in which we want to display corresponding name, we'll have to filter the `ForeignKeyTable` for each row separately. This is where `ng-controller` for `ng-repeat` comes in handy. What we'll do is bind new controller for each table row generated by `ng-repeat` and put some logic inside that controller. In HTML it would look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in primaryKeyTable" ng-controller="itemController">
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

And we'll have to define new controller in JS file:

```
app.controller('itemController', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Now we can have separate logic for each row in the table. So that's a place to filter `ForeignKeyTable` to find corresponding item and display it's name.

Since whole code is kind of big I've put it in the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xccgnpxoPHg6vhXWPwZn?p=preview

See what you can do with it.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the issue I was having with assigning the correct ID when selecting from the drop-down. I am still having an issue with the `ng-model` showing the `ForeignKeyTable.ForeignKeyName` in place of the `PrimaryTable.ForeignKeyID` in the actual table. Is there an easy way of doing that? I tried `ng-model = $label`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you pls update the question, so I can see the code?

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it helps explain what I am looking for. Basically I just want the `ForeignKeyName` to be displayed instead of the `ForeignKeyID` that I had previously in my ng-model.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should change `ng-model="p.ForeignKeyID"` to something else like  `ng-model="selectedKey"`.

Comment: That would not allow me to link the ID to the Name though when the table loads initially. When the table loads, if `p.ForeignKeyID` is equal to 10 then I would want the textbox to display the `f.ForeignKeyName` that has the ID of `ForeignKeyID = 10`. And since I want this for every row, I thought the ng-model was the way to do it. By setting `ng-model = "selectedKey"`, it doesn't display the name values for me unless I make a change.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope this will, help you ;)

Comment: Thank you for the continued help. I am trying this out but I am having to translate it a bit to fit my current layout, since I am uitilizing a few extra tools that deal with controllers (ngRoute's $routeProvider) and will get back to see if this works for me.

Comment: Good news is that I got it to work (somewhat). Bad news is that it works only sometimes and I think it has to do with me loading in my tables via an API. The issue is that the code gets to the `getForeignKeyItem()` and the `$scope.ForeignKeyTable` is still empty and will crash if I do not put an If statement before. It does work (somewhat) if my tables are large enough that it slows the loading of the page by quite a few seconds, which I dont necessarily want either. I am going to be looking into a way to speed up my API calls, maybe going Async, but either way I'm stuck.

Comment: All right. I probably shouldn't, for it's not in scope of the original question but here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ey0O1yi8w4DtFUL1zQ7H?p=preview
I've made it use `$http.get()` method to retrieve tables from json files. And assign them asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you so much, the `ng-if` combined with the boolean change in the `.then` was what I was missing. I am no longer going to ask questions here, and if i run into any other issues, I'll open a new question. Thank you again for all of the help.